# Filter job ads by salary?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The job positions displayed in the "Looking for a job?" banner are mostly low-end positions.

I have nothing against low-end positions per se (we all need to start somewhere) but I am at a stage in my career where they do not interest me, and frankly their salary is just too low.

Is it possible to filter jobs positions by salary, so that only relevant positions in which I could be interested are displayed?

Comment: I think part of why so many jobs here are advertised as low salary ones is because people tend to fill senior positions via internals and recruiters, not website ads.

Comment: @Magisch: Maybe... or just because some companies are more aggressive than others. I've personally be contacted for senior positions a couple times via SO Careers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes! We support filtering using some [advanced search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs) that lets you filter salary using min/max and inclusive ranges.

For example, to filter for all jobs that pay > 100,000 USD you can specify
[`salary:100000USD`](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=salary%3A100000USD). You can leave out the `USD` if you're actually in the US - we pick up the currency from your geo-location.

One thing to be aware of though is that 20% of our jobs have salary on them so you'll be excluding 80% of jobs by using this filter. We're aware of how important salary data is to developers and we're working to get more jobs with that data but we're not there yet.

You can also update your match preferences by using the cog on the matches tab. Here you can specify your salary requirement and this will factor into the algorithm we use to surface jobs that we think match your preferences. This uses salary as a *weight* in addition to a bunch of other factors so it isn't susceptible to the filtering issues mentioned above.

UPDATE: I should mention that this doesn't help ads right now. There is on-going work to use match preferences data in ads.

Comment: `salary` isn't documented in the linked help page. Can that (and other options) be added?

Comment: @Andy apologies, I've updated the help center.

Comment: @DeanWard: Thanks Dean! I did notice that not all ads mentioned their salary (or salary ranges). Unfortunately I do not search actively for jobs, only clicks on ads from time to time... but of late they are filled with positions with such a low salary that I've pretty much trained myself to ignore them completely.

Comment: Does filtering even work? I just tried filtering by salary on the jobs page and no matter what I entered the results appeared to stay the same.

Comment: @Brett works for me. Can you give details?

Comment: @Brett or post as a new question so we can investigate further.

Comment: @DeanWard Done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322610/sorting-jobs-by-salary-doesnt-work-same-result-set-each-time

Comment: @DeanWard The `advanced search syntax` link is dead.

Comment: @jacefarm thanks, fixed