# Filtering jobs by salary doesn't work - same result set each time

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm trying to filter jobs by salary but no matter what salary I put in it doesn't seem to change the result set; I don't know if it's *exactly* the same as I can't see anywhere where it mention how many results where found, but it *appears* to be the same as jobs with lower salaries than I input are still displaying.

What I am doing:

- Going to the [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) page
- Then clicking the *Edit match preferences* or the **cog** icon to the right of the *matches* link

This brings up the match preferences, of which I scroll down to the bottom and enter a value into the *Minimum Annual Compensation* field and leave the currency set to **USD**.

Once I click **Save** the results reload but there doesn't seem to be any changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** What you're looking for is the [salary filter](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=salary%3A40000USD..50000) provided by [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs)

Match preferences are a way to provide *hints* as to which jobs might be more interesting to you. They don't act as a filter.

In the "matches" tab, this information is leveraged in order to bring interesting jobs closer to the top of the list.

Currently, and put simply, the salary information provided in match preferences act as a "tie-breaker". When two jobs seem to equally match your interests (location, tags, ...), we'll place the one which matches your preferred salary range above the one which doesn't.

Comment: Hmmmmm ok, gt it. I guess the placement of those controls is a little confusing then, but I guess they also control the default display of the jobs on the main jobs page.

Comment: @Brett We have plans to make this interface clearer, it's in the works. Stay tuned!