# Configurable option to hide job ads without salary bracket or below a threshold?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I have seen this:

[Filter job ads by salary?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320540/filter-job-ads-by-salary)

Unfortunately it is already marked as `status-completed` when in fact it's not:

> UPDATE: I should mention that this doesn't help ads right now. There is on-going work to use match preferences data in ads.