# Upcoming improvements to job search

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, search

As a part of our continuing efforts to help developers out there get the best jobs they can get, we're proud to announce that starting later this week all of you will be able to use the new and improved job search we've been working on! (و ˃̵ᴗ˂̵)و

Here's what it'll look like:

[image: New and improved job search]

Ok, so it looks pretty — **but what's new?**

### The best results first, sorted by your matches

We revamped our search algorithm, so you'll get more personalized search results. That means the most relevant results, depending on your job match preferences, will be surfaced to the top. You'll still be able to sort your results by date, but you'll now be able to put your matches first too. You'll also be able to edit [your match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) without having to change pages:

[image: Where to sort by matches, and edit match preferences]

You may have seen [our recent announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/salary-transparency/) of [the Stack Overflow salary and skills calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator), developed as a part of our endeavor to improve the hiring process for devs, and with the objective of empowering job seekers with as much information as possible. To get you closer to the goal of having as much transparency as possible with regards to compensation when looking for the right job, you'll also be able to sort your search results by salary.

We've also ajaxified the page, making search considerably faster.

### Filter jobs by technology, salary, and more

Remember [all this stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs) you were able to do if you knew your search-fu? Well, now you'll be able to use the new search filters to quickly and easily refine your search by criteria that matter most to you:

[image: Where you can get to the new search filters]

Once the filters panel is open, you'll be able to filter your search results by tech, compensation, perks, background, and company.

[image: Available options you can sort by]

It'll be possible to specify tech you like and dislike, [the minimum compensation of the listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320540/1328704), the minimum and maximum experience level and job type (permanent, contract, or both), as well as companies you like and dislike:

[image: Company filter option]

That means [hiding all jobs from a specific company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318861/1328704) (maybe [because you've worked there already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312795/1328704)) will be possible in a pretty straightforward way, as will specifying which companies or industries you'd like to work in.

### New job notifications

Getting updates about new jobs that match your criteria delivered straight to your inbox will be easier than ever:

[image: "Create alert" option]

For specific queries, hitting the button will automatically create a new alert and we'll send you the newest jobs. If you leave the search criteria empty, you can specify whether you'd like to get notified about new jobs sorted by matches (thanks to the aforementioned new search algorithm) or date:

[image: Create job alert pop-up]

### Looks neat! Now what?

The new job search will roll out to half of the community today, and to everyone later this week. We conducted several rounds of user tests as we built our new and improved job search, but as always, we may have missed something. So if you happen to stumble upon any bugs once the new search is enabled for you, please report them either by posting them as an answer to this question or by posting questions with the tags [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) and [search](/questions/tagged/search).

Comment: First bug: I don't see the unicorn head on the tab.

Comment: Do the items in returned as matches get sorted by date, or are we still going to see 4 week old results above new day old results? [Related discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312540/on-jobs-how-do-i-sort-by-most-recent-matches)

Comment: If you wanna get results sorted by date, @Andy, there's an option for that. Sorting it by matches puts the listings that best match your match preferences closer to the top, and the best matches are not always the most recent listings. And that was the most instances of "match" I could fit into a sentence... :P

Comment: Rolling it out only a bit later today, @JonH ;)

Comment: I don't understand why date factors into best matches. Why does something that was posted weeks ago get listed higher than something brand new? They both "match" my preferences. But, if something is weeks old, I'd probably seen it. By posting it above the newer posts, you are pushing the new items further down (or off) my screen. At a glance, I can't see if there are new jobs that match preferences I set. Instead, I have to scroll through the *entire* page to see if there is something new.

Comment: The thing is that date does _not_ factor into best matches, @Andy. Something that was posted weeks ago gets listed higher than something brand new if it matches better against your preferences, regardless of its post date. So going back to my initial comment: you can either float the the most recent listings to the top, or the ones that best match your preferences. We do understand that this may bury more recent listings that you may not have seen yet, though — thanks for that feedback; it will be taken into consideration in future developments on this.

Comment: @Andy To correct JNat's comment, the date does play a small role in the matching algorithm, because people are *generally* interested in newer jobs (but not always). As you pointed out, since you have visited the site recently, you have seen some of these jobs already. This information should be leveraged so that newer jobs are ranked higher. That's something we need to work on... 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: "Tech you dislike: PHP" it's gotten bad enough that disliking PHP is now the defaults? :P

Comment: Hooray, no lame memes this time! (و ˃̵ᴗ˂̵)و

Comment: good luck with jobs. this is good initiative. I'd like to see more remote jobs options, and also possibility to choose level of experience: senior, junior, etc.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I got my first job abroad from Stack Overflow Jobs a month ago and I'm typing this comment from the company provided Mac <3

Comment: [Is there any hope of getting the "stupid IP based location" of the adverts fixed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317083/542251)

Comment: @Liam it's [tag:status-planned] but there's a few other things on the backlog first. Soon!

Comment: Can we make jobs that don't have salaries only show via an opt-in checkbox? Including in the job ads I see on the sidebar, etc.? That's really annoying to have a job shoved in my face when it doesn't meet criteria I would always use when searching.

Comment: @TylerH In job search, you can use the salary filter to only show jobs which meet certain salary criteria. Integrating salary preferences in job ads is not on the roadmap yet, but feel free to make a feature request via a new question.

Comment: The circles aren't freehand!

Comment: Excellent work UX team.

Comment: this is a really cute new smiley. thanks for letting me meet them

Comment: Hasn't this been featured for long enough?

Answer (score 74):

I'm not sure if an answer is the best place to put this, but: I wish we could specify a shorter distance than 20 miles. Or maybe even a directional offset.

In a straight line I live within 20 miles of Central London... yet I don't live in London; nor do I especially want to. Here's a map:

[image: London and Me]

The striped area is Central London; the big red area around it is [Greater London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_London); and the orange circle is roughly where I live.

I'm not all that interested in commuting anywhere into that big red area. I am however interested in commuting to the north, south and west of where I live.

I propose three ideas on how this could be tackled:

- Allow us to specify shorter distances.
- Allow us to sort the resultset by distance (at least this way I'd get the results closer to home before getting all the Central London ones).
- Allow us to offset the direction (e.g. 20 miles to the west (although admittedly this sounded a lot more awesome in my head, now it just sounds a little stupid)).

That said, the UK property website RightMove has a nifty [*draw a search* feature](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/draw-a-search.html) which allows you to draw on a map to pinpoint exactly where you'd like to live. Something like this would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: We're discussing it right now... Will let you know when we have come to a decision!

Comment: @DeanWard What about making an option "Locations/Cities to exclude" similar to the "Tech you dislike" and "Companies to exclude" which will simply filter out any results that have a location with a matching name?

Comment: @TotZam - Its a lot of work to get every city in there...and what if someone misspells it?

Comment: @JonH You should not need to create any list of cities. It should be free-form text input like the "Tech you like" section currently is. If someone misspells something, when the city they want to exclude still shows up, they hopefully will realize and correct the mistake. It is not any different than if they misspell any other filter.

Comment: Travel time including public transport would be a good option, as in London distance is not a good indicator of travel time.   For example a lot of people are only interested in jobs that are within walking distance of a station they can get a direct train to.

Comment: @IanRingrose funnily enough we do have some data on how people search for jobs and how their commutes would look. I'll bring it up with the data team to see where that research got to.

Comment: @TotZam we'll consider it, it'll likely be a geo lookup like the regular location field

Comment: We're just testing out some things around distance options and sorting, hopefully will have something to ship soon.

Comment: @DeanWard, be very careful, as people that need a "public transport travel time search" to make your site useful, are unlikely to be current users!   Just changing a office location by 2 miles can often add 1hr to the travel time.

Comment: @IanRingrose agreed, more considering it from how we can make the data we have useful in some way... Commute distance is practically impossible to estimate, especially in the big cities like London or New York.

Comment: @DeanWard maps.google.co.uk can do it, if you ask for public transport directions arriving by 9am, https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/ can also be used within London.   Therefore the data is out there.   You "just" need to create a table that has the public transport travel time between each pair of postcodes.....

Comment: @IanRingrose absolutely, yet time of day and various other factors come into play here so any estimate is likely to be wildly off depending on those factors. I think we'd *rather not* get in the business of commute estimation... I'll bring it up with the team and see if we can think up a useful feature from the data we have and some of the meta feedback.

Comment: The source code for http://www.mapnificent.net/ is on git hub and may help.

Comment: Alternatively, a collapsible map showing job openings would also allow you to target listings outside of your no zone.

Comment: Something related to that, would be to allow to search in the European Community, instead to need to add each country. I feel annoyed when in other websites I can't do that.

Comment: @DeanWard: suggesting "location exclude" option (will work together with include). Example : include any job within 30km of my postal code but exclude Toronto Downtown +10km - something like that. Just specifying location to exclude is not enough, being able to provide radius is essential.

Comment: I second this idea!

Comment: How about just showing the jobs on a map, à la AirBnB? That way the user can make their own mind up...

Comment: How often do you search for a new job? Your comment "Something like this would make my life a lot easier." makes me wonder.

Answer (score 5):

When I want to edit the match process, the "Tech you want to work with" only list the technologies of the filtered list of jobs (for instance those in X location). Shouldn't it be general? I mean showing all the technologies I like, even if in this specific search there aren't jobs with technology Y?

Also I have selected two industries for my match, however almost all I see are other type of industries. How is the industry taken into account? I suppose it could be due to lack of information provided by companies... but I found an interesting company which list the industry as "Bioinformatics, Biotechnology, Computer Software" which is not listed as tag for my match criteria. How are those included in the match engine?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're talking about your [job match preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) when you talk about tags? The list of tags it uses is the full list from SO; it's definitely not restricted to what's used by any of the jobs currently running on /jobs.

Comment: Regarding industries: our data mining has not yet shown a high correlation between people that pick industries and apply to jobs in those industries, so *right now* it doesn't give substantial weight to jobs with matching industries. But... that is likely down to not enough companies having the data and not enough devs having filled in that aspect of their  preferences... over time we expect the matching to become more accurate.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that job match preferences, the list is the same as SO, but If I filtered to look only jobs in Spain, and in Spain the technologies they look for are Perl and Python, if in my  job match preferences I have Perl, Python, and Java, only the first two are shown on the bubble of match preferences, on the right panel at http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: Can you add screenshots please?

Comment: How are those tags for industries selected? Maybe if they are extracted from the definition of companies (instead of a predefined list made by ??) it would improve the matching.

Comment: It's a hierarchical list defined by industries entered by companies. The problem is not that things don't match, it's that other things have been given a higher weight in the matching algorithm. Match preferences are not filters, they're assigned weights to give a sorted list.

Comment: Maybe it was cache, but now I couldn't reproduce it. neither the "ops there was a problem" it appeared before effectively changing the filter. It also might be due to my browser :(

Answer (score 0):

For the Company section, I propose that for Industry, there is an input for *excluding* industries.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request; you should create a separate post for it ;)

Comment: [I did!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339307/offer-an-input-to-exclude-industries-in-job-search)

Answer (score -2):

In the `perks` section, you can specify that you want to include companies that offer remote work.  Without playing around with the search results, it isn't clear if checking that setting means "show me only remote jobs" or "show me jobs that are either remote or near the specified location" (and similarly, what it means to have it un-checked).

---

It would be really nice to be able to filter on various company attributes, most notably company size.

Comment: These sound like feature requests: would you mind posting them separately as such? Feature requests lose visibility if they get posted as answers instead.