# Offer an input to exclude industries in job search

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

The [Upcoming Improvements to Job Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336846/upcoming-improvements-to-job-search/339306#339306) are great, but in general, I would propose an input to *exclude* industries that are not of interest for job seekers.

It's interesting. Almost every search feature available does not include this type of filtering.  What I wouldn't give to filter out `Kardashian` from a news feed, for instance.  They'll feed you anything, but it always includes what you're not interested in...

Comment: It depends on who is considered the user for *jobs* […]. If recruiters are then it would be detrimental for them and hence won't be implemented.

Comment: @Knu Excellent point. I've clarified for _job seekers_.

Comment: Agree this would be useful. Considering as part of our 2017 roadmap - deferring until we have more concrete plans.

Comment: @Donna Any updated? It would really helpful to narrow down the number of relatable jobs...

Comment: I would like to exclude Adult and Gambling industries. Right now, this is not possible.